# Dynamically Pause YouTube Video via Unfocused Window from FancyBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, youtube, fancybox

I already know how to play/pause a YouTube video dynamically as you can see from [my weave](http://mikethedj4.github.io/kodeWeave/editor/#8d47a5b359582487390ebba52757ea9e).

However I'm having difficulty getting it to work dynamically with FancyBox using onBlur (when the window is not focused video should pause).

Here's my Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJXoJy?editors=0010

```js
// Show Lightbox Video Onload
$.fancybox.open({
  youtube : {
    controls : 0,
    showinfo : 0
  },
  src  : '//www.youtube.com/embed/-AszZcClVXA?enablejsapi=1', // Source of the content
  type : 'iframe', // Content type: image|inline|ajax|iframe|html (optional)
});

// Inject YouTube API script
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady(e) {
  // create the global player from the specific iframe (#video)
  player = new YT.Player($(".fancybox-iframe").attr("id"), {
    events: {
      // call this function when player is ready to use
      'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerReady() {
  window.addEventListener("blur", function() {
    player.pauseVideo();
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.min.css?v=1490320405" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.min.js?v=1490320405"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo - http://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/jBKowp?editors=1010

Basically, idea is that you initialize fancyBox after YouTube API is available and then you can use YouTube API methods inside fancyBox callback.

```
// 1. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// 2. This function initializes fancyBox
//    after the API code downloads.
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

  $('[data-fancybox="group"]').fancybox({
    onComplete : function( instance, current ) {

      if ( current.type === 'iframe' ) {
        var id = current.$content.find('iframe').attr('id');

        player = new YT.Player( id, {
          events : {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }
    }

  });

}

// 3. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.playVideo();
}

// 4. Fires when the player's state changes.
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    // Go to the next video after the current one is finished playing
    if (event.data === 0) {
        $.fancybox.getInstance('next');
    }
}

// Page Visibility API to pause video when window is not active
$(document).on("visibilitychange", function() {
  if ( player ) {
    if ( document.hidden ) {
      player.pauseVideo();
    } else {
      player.playVideo();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You're only pausing the video on blur. Why not use mouseover event to play and mouseout event to pause the video?

Comment: Because this is being done for an Android application and the video plays when the phone is locked which is against Google's policies. I tried using `document.addEventListener("pause")` but it didn't work that way either. The problem is getting it to work dynamically with FancyBox.

Comment: Is this only meant for mobile?

Comment: Like I said the problem is getting this to work dynamically with FancyBox. I'm using window.onblur here that way it'll be faster to resolve on desktop. If I/We can figure out how to get it to pause using onblur with FancyBox then I'll be able to get it to work in PhoneGap using the pause event listener